# Do contact binaries such as Ultima Thule affect our current theories on how the Moon formed?

Tags: the-moon, contact-binaries

While I was reading about [Ultima Thule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(486958)_2014_MU69), I was wondering if the discovery of contact binary objects had any effect on our current theories of how the Moon formed?

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at here. What effect could it have had?

Comment: @JamesK the most widelly spread hypotesis is the big impact hypotesis, I was wondering if there contact binaries might be grounds for a new hypostesis